# Python: String to Dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary, literals

I've read through a couple StackOverflow posts on turning a string into a dictionary. I am trying to follow an example using `ast.literal_eval` and can't figure out where i'm going wrong. I believe i'm putting the string in the right format...

String: `"{'platform_name': 'TSC2_commander', 'tracks': '52', 'time': '150'}"`

Code: `newdictionary = ast.literal_eval('"' + str(word) +'"')`

But when I try to print `print(newdictionary.get('Platform_Name'))` I get "Str object has no attribute 'get'. Can someone teach me what i'm doing wrong?

Comment: You are making it too complicated. Just use `literal_eval(word)` without trying to convert an already existing string to another string and adding more quotes on top.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
from ast import literal_eval
a_string = "{'platform_name': 'TSC2_commander', 'tracks': '52', 'time': '150'}"

a_dict = literal_eval(a_string)
print(a_dict['platform_name'])
```

Output:

```
TSC2_commander
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem is with how ast is interpreting the string you give it.
If the string of the dictionary itself does not contain quotes, it will be interpreted as what you intend.

```
    >>> import ast
    >>> dictionary = ast.literal_eval("{'a': 1, 'b': 2}")
    >>> print(type(dictionary))
    <class 'dict'>
    >>> dictionary.get('a')
    1
```

But if the string you give ast itself has quotes around it, it will be interpreted as a string.

```
    >>> newdictionary = ast.literal_eval('"' + str("{'a':1, 'b':2}") + '"')
    >>> print(type(newdictionary))
    <class 'str'>
    >>> print(newdictionary)
    {'a':1, 'b':2}
    >>>
```

Answer (score 1):

Please take a look sample output:

```
import ast
my_string = "{'key':'val','key1':'value'}"
my_dict = ast.literal_eval(my_string)
```

Output:

```
{'key': 'val', 'key1': 'value'}
```

Comment: Do not put image of terminal please, this is not noce at all